# PHP7 couchbase module compilation

Tags: php, couchbase, php-7

i try to compile php-couchbase (https://github.com/couchbase/php-couchbase) with PHP7 but after phpize, ./configure on make receive this error:

```
In file included from /home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1:0:
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c: In function 'zim_Bucket_http_request':
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/couchbase.h:44:23: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 #define PHP_THISOBJ() zend_object_store_get_object(getThis() TSRMLS_CC)
                       ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1136:24: note: in expansion of macro 'PHP_THISOBJ'
  bucket_object *data = PHP_THISOBJ();
                        ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c: In function 'zim_Bucket_durability':
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/couchbase.h:44:23: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 #define PHP_THISOBJ() zend_object_store_get_object(getThis() TSRMLS_CC)
                       ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1203:24: note: in expansion of macro 'PHP_THISOBJ'
  bucket_object *data = PHP_THISOBJ();
                        ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c: In function 'zim_Bucket_setTranscoder':
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/couchbase.h:44:23: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 #define PHP_THISOBJ() zend_object_store_get_object(getThis() TSRMLS_CC)
                       ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1268:24: note: in expansion of macro 'PHP_THISOBJ'
  bucket_object *data = PHP_THISOBJ();
                        ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1275:2: warning: passing argument 1 of '_zval_ptr_dtor' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  zval_ptr_dtor(&data->encoder);
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/couchbase.h:11,
                 from /home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_variables.h:112:15: note: expected 'struct zval *' but argument is of type 'struct zval **'
 ZEND_API void _zval_ptr_dtor(zval *zval_ptr ZEND_FILE_LINE_DC);
               ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1279:2: warning: passing argument 1 of '_zval_ptr_dtor' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  zval_ptr_dtor(&data->decoder);
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:36,
                 from /home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/couchbase.h:11,
                 from /home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_variables.h:112:15: note: expected 'struct zval *' but argument is of type 'struct zval **'
 ZEND_API void _zval_ptr_dtor(zval *zval_ptr ZEND_FILE_LINE_DC);
               ^
In file included from /home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1:0:
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c: In function 'zim_Bucket_setOption':
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/couchbase.h:44:23: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 #define PHP_THISOBJ() zend_object_store_get_object(getThis() TSRMLS_CC)
                       ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1288:24: note: in expansion of macro 'PHP_THISOBJ'
  bucket_object *data = PHP_THISOBJ();
                        ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c: In function 'zim_Bucket_getOption':
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/couchbase.h:44:23: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 #define PHP_THISOBJ() zend_object_store_get_object(getThis() TSRMLS_CC)
                       ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1304:24: note: in expansion of macro 'PHP_THISOBJ'
  bucket_object *data = PHP_THISOBJ();
                        ^
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c: In function 'couchbase_init_bucket':
/home/ubuntu/php-couchbase/bucket.c:1345:19: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  ce.create_object = bucket_create_handler;
                   ^
make: *** [bucket.lo] Error 1
```

Couchbase not help us, and PHP7 it's important for performance improvement. We try with HHVM but we can't compile couchbase module.

Thanks,
Jacopo

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Couchbase PHP SDK does not currently support PHP 7, there are plans to add support to the SDK as per https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/PCBC-360, however there is not a scheduled release date for adding this support yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile php-couchbase using the php7 branch  (https://github.com/couchbase/php-couchbase/tree/php7).

Comment: Note that that is being semi-regularly updated, and the code review is here: http://review.couchbase.org/#/q/status:open+project:php-couchbase+branch:php7